# estimated proportion of 2 percent although all events were zero in single arm meta-analysis using meta package

Tags: r, meta-analysis, proportion, metafor

I am trying to do single arm meta-analysis using `meta` and `metafor` packages in `R`; however, although all events were 0, I got estimated proportion of 0.02 (0.01-0.06).
I just want to confirm that this makes sense as I thought it should be 0 as well.

Here is my code:

```
library(meta); library(metafor)

data<- read.table(text = "
studlab Number.of.patients  Procedure   events
Lee 2015    15  SPT 0
Wang 2019   44  SPT 0
chira 2018  12  SPT 0
Zhang 2020  20  SPT 0
Lee 2017    48  SPT 0
Weiping Hu 2018 28  SPT 0
Zhu 2021    19  SPM 0
", sep="\t",header=T)

mp<-metaprop(events,Number.of.patients, data=data, studlab=studlab,  method = "Inverse",method.tau = "DL");mp


### Results#
# Number of studies combined: k = 7
# Number of observations: o = 186
# Number of events: e = 0
# 
# proportion           95%-CI
# Common effect model      0.0202 [0.0071; 0.0562]
# Random effects model     0.0202 [0.0071; 0.0562]
# 
# Quantifying heterogeneity:
#   tau^2 = 0; tau = 0; I^2 = 0.0% [0.0%; 70.8%]; H = 1.00 [1.00; 1.85]
#   
#   Test of heterogeneity:
#     Q d.f. p-value
#   0.78    6  0.9927
#   
#   Details on meta-analytical method:
#     - Inverse variance method
#   - DerSimonian-Laird estimator for tau^2
#   - Logit transformation
#   - Continuity correction of 0.5 in studies with zero cell frequencies
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated

Comment: "Continuity correction of 0.5 in studies with zero cell frequencies" means the software added data that weren't observed.  That shouldn't be a big deal because the story is extremely simple: as I interpret your code, no "events" were observed in these studies, period.  That summary statement is about all the statistical analysis you need to do--*anything* else you do will depend on additional assumptions that you and the software make, some of which might be untenable or unsupported.  Spend your time evaluating the studies and describing them to your audience.

Comment: @whuber Thx for your explanation. I got your point now. I am still searching the `meta` package to see if there is a way to fix the code to avoid such continuity correction and the resulting forest plot. Appreciate your guidance. Upvoted.

Comment: The manual for `meta` (at p. 165) states, "Continuity correction:
If the summary measure is equal to "PLOGIT", "PLN", or "PRAW", a continuity correction is applied if any study has either zero or all events, i.e., an event probability of either 0 or 1. By default, 0.5 is used as continuity correction (argument incr). This continuity correction is used both to calculate individual study results with confidence limits and to conduct meta-analysis based on the inverse variance method. For GLMMs no continuity correction is used."

Answer (score 2):

Under the assumption of homogeneity, the sum of independent binomial counts also follows a binomial distribution. Hence, there are then 0 events out of `sum(data$Number.of.patients)` (i.e., 186) patients. One could then use the 'rule of 3' to compute a CI (see [here](https://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_16/16_9_4_confidence_intervals_when_no_events_are_observed.htm) for details) or simply compute the Clopper-Pearson CI with `binom.test(0, sum(data$Number.of.patients))`, which yields the bounds `0` to `0.0196`.

Comment: Thx for your answer.  I got it and I see that I can get the results using your code. However, I am still searching the `meta` package to see if there is a way to fix the code to avoid such continuity correction and the resulting forest plot. Appreciate your guidance and time. Upvoted.

Comment: If you don't apply a continuity correction, all proportions and their sampling variances will be 0. The usual 'inverse-variance method' then breaks down, since you will get division by zero when computing the weights.